# ogr2ogr MIF to KML fails on writing kml in linux

Tags: kml, ogr2ogr, mif

I have multiple MIF files which I would like to translate to KML format.

> ogr2ogr -f "KML" geo-mif geo-kml
>
> FAILURE:
>
> Unable to open datasource `geo-kml' with the following drivers.

It seems that ogr2ogr has issues writing KML.

Do I need to install something additional?

Other formats like Mapinfo file works like a charm e.g.:  ogr2ogr -f "Mapinfo file" geo-kml geo-mif works perfectly

Comment: installed expat but no luck so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your input and output datasets in the wrong order. The (rather unintuitive) [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) syntax is:

```
ogr2ogr [options] dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name [layers]
```

Use the following instead:

```
ogr2ogr -f "KML" geo-kml geo-mif
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing Expat won't be enough - you need to rebuild OGR with expat support.

From http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_kml.html:

> KML reading is only available if GDAL/OGR is *built* with the Expat XML
>   Parser, otherwise only KML writing will be supported.